# How can I trigger a second animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, chain

I have a bunch of these 90x900 images that drop down on page load. The animation for that is just added in the parent element selecting all li's in the list, which are the images. The images initial position is -1000px, and have a css animation  to transform from 0px to 1000px on the Y Axis, and they stay there with 
`animation-fill-mode: forwards`.

I want it so when I click a button they return to their initial position of -1000px.

These are my animations, first one is the initial page load animation, second one is what I want to trigger on click.

```
@keyframes mainpic {
from {transform: translateY(0px);}
to {transform: translateY(1000px);}
}

@keyframes mainpicleave {
    from {transform: translateY(1000px);}
    to {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

So I added the page load animation to `.main-pic li` so it adds it to every `li` in the `ul`. And then I set an `animation-delay` of 0.2s more than the last one on every `li`.

```
.main-pic li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    top: -1000px;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px black;
    animation-name: mainpic;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.main-pic-01 {
    background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-01.png');
    height: 900px;
    width: 90px;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.main-pic-02 {
    background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-02.png');
    height: 900px;
    width: 90px;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

So I thought I could just add another class with an animation on it with jQuery. I made this class:

```
.main-pic-toggle-leave {
    animation-name: mainpicleave;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

So I tried a couple different things with jQuery. I thought maybe if I removed the pre exisiting class with the initial animation on it, and then had a `toggleClass` on it, that it would work. But it does not.

```
$('#btn_01').click(function(){
    $('.main-pic-01').toggleClass('main-pic li');
    $('.main-pic-01').toggleClass('main-pic-toggle-leave');
});
```

Not sure what else I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: instead of animation, you can use `transition`. Then you can toggle some class on click and specify the 'after transition' state in this class.

Comment: What is purpose of `"li`" at `.toggleClass('main-pic li');`?

Comment: Are you trying to animate element vertically at click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a separate class for `animation` properties for `.main-pic li` elements at `css`; animate `top` instead of `transform`; set `animation-fill-mode` to `both` at `.main-pic-toggle-leave`

```js
$('#btn_01').click(function() {
  $(".main-pic-01").toggleClass('animation');
  $(".main-pic-01").toggleClass('main-pic-toggle-leave');
});
```

```css
.main-pic li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px black;
  top: -1000px;
}
.animation {
  animation-name: mainpic;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
.main-pic-01 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/900/90/nature");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 900px;
  width: 90px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.main-pic-02 {
  background-image: url();
  height: 900px;
  width: 90px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.main-pic-toggle-leave {
  animation-name: mainpicleave;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes mainpic {
  from {
    top: -1000px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes mainpicleave {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: -1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_01">click</button>
<ul class="main-pic">
  <li class="main-pic-01 animation"></li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of animation, you can use transition. Then you can toggle some class on click and specify the 'after transition' state in this class

```js
$("#trigger").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#block").toggleClass("moved");
});//#button click

$(window).on("load", function(){
  $("#trigger").trigger("click");
});//window load
```

```css
#block
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

#block.moved
{
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>

<button id="trigger">Move</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this, think this will ultimately work. Only problem is that the initial animation is only set to run when the button is clicked. I want the initial animation to run on page load. And then toggle on and off with button click.

Comment: You can either add the class on page load, or simply `trigger` the click event on the button on page load. I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It's coming along. Last problem is that previously, each image would be delayed by 0.2s before the next one triggered the animation. I tried `transition-delay` on the `li` itself. But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: '.main-pic-01 {
 background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-01.png');
 height: 900px;
 width: 90px;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.main-pic-02 {
 background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-02.png');
 height: 900px;
 width: 90px;
 transition-delay: 0.4s;
}'

Comment: oops. 

`.main-pic-01 {
 background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-01.png');
 height: 900px;
 width: 90px;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.main-pic-02 {
 background-image: url('../images/dropdown-main/main-pic-02.png');
 height: 900px;
 width: 90px;
 transition-delay: 0.4s;
}`

Tried this.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand the requirement properly. Do you mean you have multiple images, which on page load will all animate to right with a delay of 0.2s between them? And then on button click, all images would come back to initial position or each one individually?

Comment: No, they all start at -1000px on the Y Axis. And on page load animate down to 1000px. So they all pop in. There are 16 of them in total. Each one is separated by 0.2s, so they create a kind of staircase effect when coming in, but they all stop at the same position, just each one is a little behind the previous one.